# @yield stops me from harvesting the DOM

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

So, I have standard app.blade.php file and home.blade.php file, the app has an @yield build in Laravel functionality, but the problem is that when I try select and render an event listener it doesn't work but when I do it from app, it works.

Home -

```
<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>

<script>
    $( "p" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).slideUp();
    });
</script>
```

it doesn't work

app -

```
 <main class="py-4">
        @yield('content')
    </main>
</div>

<p>First Paragraph</p>
<p>Second Paragraph</p>
<p>Yet one more Paragraph</p>
<script>
    $( "p" ).click(function() {
        console.log(123);
    });
</script>
```

Works!...

Answer (score 1):

You are probally trying to manipulate a node when the DOM is not ready.

Make sure you wrap your code around

```
$( document ).ready(function(){})
```

This will tell the DOM to only execute what is inside of `.ready(function(){})` whenever the DOM has loaded fully.

Answer (score 0):

did you extend the master template for home.blade.php?

```
@yield('content')
```

mostly @yield is placed in the master template where all the js and css are placed.
can you edit and put all the code of app.blade and home.blade so we can check it.